# C# Petición httpGet usando FromHeader (no consigo pasarle argumentos)

Tags: c#, .net, http-get

muy buenas, querría obtener una serie de determinados objetos usando Skip() y Take(), pero cuando en mi controlador los uso no consigo pasarle el parametro int de skip en el headers

Mi método:

```
[Route("getSome")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Pelicula> GetSome([FromHeader] int saltadas)
    {
        List<Pelicula> peliculas = _context.Pelicula
            .Include(i => i.Creador)
            .Include(i => i.TipoPelicula)
            .Include(i => i.ClasificacionEdad)
            .Where(w => w.EstaBorrado == false)
            .ToList();

        return peliculas.Skip(saltadas).Take(2);
    }
```

Usando Postman y pasándole el parámetro "saltadas" desde el header no me lo coge, alguna idea de por qué puede ser esto? Lo he probado desde el cliente y tampoco. Gracias a todos de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final no conseguí pasarlo por el header, pero encontré una alternativa que me hizo el apaño, lo paso por aquí para el que le venga bien:

```
 [HttpGet("getSome/{saltadas}", Name = "getSome")]
    public IEnumerable<Pelicula> GetSome( int saltadas )
    {
        if (saltadas == null) {
            saltadas = 0;
        }

        List<Pelicula> peliculas = _context.Pelicula
            .Include(i => i.Creador)
            .Include(i => i.TipoPelicula)
            .Include(i => i.ClasificacionEdad)
            .Where(w => w.EstaBorrado == false)
            .ToList();

        return peliculas.Skip(saltadas).Take(100);
    }
```

Comment: incluso usando  [HttpGet("getSome/{saltadas}/{coger}", Name = "getSome")] si quieres pasarle tanto una cifra como la otra desde el cliente.